# I'm getting a conversion error in my C++ solution for TSP

Tags: c++, codeblocks, traveling-salesman

I am attempting to solve TSP in C++ with a multidimensional array and am receiving an error message about type conversion.

I've gotten rusty on C++ having not used it in a few years, so to relearn I decided to try a few Travelling Salesman solutions. The first I'm using uses a multidimensional array to store the points, which are being assigned randomly. That part worked fine, so I moved on to the distance formula. I created a helper function for the basic distance formula that takes 2 arrays as its input which functions fine on its own, then created a function to find the total distance of a full array of cities. It takes in an array of doubles and an integer that represents the total number of cities, then iterates through the array finding the distance for each point and adding them together.

Here's the variable declaration and random point assignment

```
    int numCities = 10;
    double cities[numCities][2];

    //Creates random(unseeded) points
    for(int i = 0; i < numCities; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            cities[i][j] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        }
    }
```

Here's the line being used to call the function

```
    cout << distTotal(cities, numCities) << endl;
```

And here's the function and helper function

```
    //basic distance formula
    double cityDist(double cityA[], double cityB[]){
        return sqrt(pow((cityB[0]-cityA[0]), 2.0)+
                    pow((cityB[1]-cityA[1]), 2.0));
    }

    //calculate total distance of group of cities
    double distTotal(double* points[], int num){
        double total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < num-1; i++){
            total=total+cityDist(points[i], points[i+1]);
        }
        return total;
    }
```

So ideally this should be giving me the total distance between all the points in the base order given here. However, I'm currently getting the following error:

> error: cannot convert 'double (*)[2]' to 'double**' for argument '1' to 'double distTotal(double**, int)'

If I remember correctly, this could have to do with pointers, but I honestly don't remember enough about C++ pointers to know how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do yourself a favour and make it a `std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 10> cities;`. You then have a `size()` function available for both dimensions and don't need to pass a companion variable around whenever you give the array as an argument to a function.

Comment: Alright, trying that. With that formatting, how do I avoid the aforementioned error?

Comment: You change the signature of the function to: `double distTotal(std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 10>& points);`

Comment: Fixed the first issue, but now it's having an issue with the helper function. Line that calls the helper function is giving `cannot convert 'std::array<std::array<double, 2u>, 10u>::value_type {aka std::array<double, 2u>}' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'double cityDist(double*, double*)'` which appears to be the same error. I changed it to use `array.size()` where appropriate and used your recommendation for creating the array and using it in the function. The helper function remains unchanged. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to change the signature of all functions appropriately `double cityDist(const std::array<double, 2>& cityA, const std::array<double, 2>& cityB);`

Comment: Right, figured it out. For future reference the '&' is because it needs to be a pointer, correct?

Comment: Close. The `&` means that the function will receive a referece to the object (instead of copying the whole thing). The `const` part means that the function promises not to change the object.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration should be `double* points` as C-arrays decay into pointers. If doing c++  you might consider using `std::vector<double>&` as an input instead.

Edit: if you end up using c-arrays you will have to allocate them on the heap and free the resources.

Comment: Okay, I'll try vectors. For the sake of my own edification, are vectors often preferable to arrays in C++?

Comment: @JordanLejman typically yes as they handle their own allocation and are dynamic.  There are cases where using c-arrays are necessary but it's rare.  The STL also has many other collection types you may find useful

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-c-standard-template-library-stl/

Comment: So wait, 2D vectors are something separate?

Comment: @JordanLejman A `vector` is one dimensional, but if the type contained by the vector is another vector (like `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`) one can call it two dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int numCities = 10;
> double cities[numCities][2];
> ```

Instead of having an anonymous pair of `double`s containing the `x` and `y` position of each city, create a `class`/`struct` for it. It'll make it easier to expand your solution later. If you'd like to store the name of the city with its position for example:

```
struct position_t {
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct city_t {
    position_t position;
    std::string name;
};
```

Then, instead of having a fixed number of cities in an array, consider using a `vector` which can grow and shrink dynamically during runtime:

```
std::vector<city_t> cities;
```

With some helper functions added:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

struct position_t {
    position_t(double X, double Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}

    double dist(const position_t& other) const {
        return std::sqrt(std::pow(x - other.x, 2.) + std::pow(y - other.y, 2.));
    }

    // a function to print the position
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const position_t&);

    double x;
    double y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const position_t& p) {
    return os << '{' << p.x << ',' << p.y << '}';
}

struct city_t {
    city_t(const position_t& p, const std::string_view& n) : position(p), name(n) {}

    double dist(const city_t& other) const {
        // this distance function just calls the function in the position_t
        return position.dist(other.position);
    }

    // a function to print the values of the city    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const city_t&);

    position_t position;
    std::string name;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const city_t& c) {
    return os << c.position << ' ' << c.name;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<city_t> cities = {{{10., 20.}, "Ankeborg"},
                                  {{11., 12.}, "Gothenburg"}};
    for(const auto& c : cities) {
        std::cout << c << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "distance: " << cities[0].dist(cities[1]) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
{10,20} Ankeborg
{11,12} Gothenburg
distance: 8.06226
```